# Register page with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to create Sign Up with Spring Security.

It has login(), logout(), but how does Spring perform register request with security?
I have no login, password when I do it. So I need to disable authorization for this page.

So, I need something like:

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register").iHaveNoLogin().iHaveNoPassword().iHaveNothing();
```

---

Fixed.
I just marked only selected pages as authorized:

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/secured_pages**") ...
```

And other pages do not require authorization.

Comment: Too big to answer here, I think. I'd recommend going through a tutorial, like this one: https://www.udemy.com/spring-framework-4/?couponCode=ME29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security does not provide a registration page for you. You have to do it yourself. It's not a complicated form to make yourself.

They are nice enough to supply the [JdbcUserDetailsManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html), and its createUser method, which can make it fast and simple to create a user in your database.